# How to avoid computer noise in studio monitors?

Tags: noise, studio-monitors

I have a M-Audio M-Track MKII (USB) and I bought a pair of Behringer studio monitors recently and using 1/4 TRS cables between them. I hear permanent noise of the cpu on the monitors, even it changes with the movements of mouse. I was using studio headphones till now and never encountered this.

Btw I use 6 socket power outlet which an UPS is connected to it and my pc is connected to the UPS. The monitors are also plugged to one of the sockets on this outlet.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: are you 100% sure that the M-Track outputs and the Behringer inputs are balanced?

Comment: Sounds like a ground loop issue. Try isolating the PC mains supply and ensuring the connections are balanced. If they are balanced, try cutting the ground line between the interface and speaker inputs.

Comment: being able to hear mouse-ing is indicative of digital noise from the audio device coupling to the analog audio output, a classic fingerprint of crappy design. I have a Focusrite Saffire that does it too...it's not too bad with balanced I/O, but unbalanced is unacceptable.

Comment: I am a bit newbie about this matter. So using 1/4 TRS cables means balanced or not?

Comment: Well that means you have balanced cables. :)  Look in the manuals for your devices and see if the inputs and outputs are balanced.

Comment: I feel like retarded really:) I can't see anything on manual as the inputs and outputs are balanced or not seriously. One thing that I found out btw is that when I plug Behringer directly with its USB to pc there is no more noise. It seems the problem is my MAudio Interface.. But what will I do with that? Should I change my usb cable? I even don't know if there is different type of cable to prevent this issue. Actually I used this same cable on Behringer monitors to plug directly pc and no noise issue. I don't know what to do..

Answer (score 1):

> One thing that I found out btw is that when I plug Behringer directly with its USB to pc there is no more noise. It seems the problem is my MAudio Interface. But what will I do with that? Should I change my usb cable?

The USB cable is unlikely to be the culprit though it's the cheapest solution so maybe worth a try. If the MAudio device supports an external power adapter (rather than just USB power) then you might try that. And try plugging it into a separate power supply than the one your PC plugs into.

The full solution is probably to invest in a higher end audio interface. For example my RME Fireface set me back £700 but I've had it for years and it does a beautiful job. Or just try different interfaces but get them through a company that has an easy return policy in case they have the same problem...

Comment: I figured out the problem is about electricity. One technician suggested me to tape the plug's ground metal pieces and it really took away the noise. But NEVER try this at home if anyone reading this because even if it is solved this didn't seem safe to me. I will call and electirician to home and ask him about a safe solution about electric line.

Comment: Oh yeah, "lifting the ground" is a classic solution amongst electric guitarists as well :)